# File chooser in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I need a File chooser in my Xamarin.Forms app, but I am thinking, if that is possible in iOS?

I know it is possible on both Android and UWP, but as iOS uses Sandboxing, I do not know, if it is possible on iOS.

Or do I have to use `Open In`,  as I then need to redesign some of my app.
And if I have to do it in that way, can I then use that method on UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [xamarin plugin file picker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.FilePicker/)

Add the click event:

```
async void OpenFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileData filedata = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.ShowException(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

But sometimes your will get the `System.NotImplementedException`

So you need to import dll for android and ios manually.

For Android you can find the dll at `your_project_name\packages\Xam.Plugin.FilePicker.1.1.0\lib\MonoAndroid10`

For IOS you can find the dll at `your_project_name\packages\Xam.Plugin.FilePicker.1.1.0\lib\MonoTouch10`

Comment: i get "This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation"